# Use EMGU to get "real world" coordinates of pixel values

Tags: emgucv

There are a number of calibration tutorials to calibrate camera images of chessboards in EMGU (OpenCV). They all end up calibrating and then undistorting an image for display. That's cool and all but I need to do machine vision where I am taking an image, identifying the location of a corner or blob or feature in the image and then translating the location of that feature in pixels into real world X, Y coordinates.

Pixel -> mm.

Is this possible with EMGU? If so, how? I'd hate to spend a bunch of time learning EMGU and then not be able to do this crucial function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible as the "bread and butter" of OpenCV.

The calibration you are describing, in terms of removing distortions, is a prerequisite to this process. After which, the following applies:

[image: PointProjection]

The Intrinsic calibration, or "camera matrix" is the first of two required matrices. The second is the Extrinsic calibration of the camera which is essentially the 6 DoF transform that describes the physical location of the sensor center relative to a coordinate reference frame.

All of the Distortion Coefficients, Intrinsic, and Extrinsic Calibrations are available from a single function in Emgu.CV: [CvInvoke.CalibrateCamera](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/2f56e7bc-7cf5-45ab-7bbe-337f1b7e102f.htm) This process is best explained, I'm sure, by one of the many tutorials available that you have described.

After that it's as simple as [CvInvoke.ProjectPoints](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.0.0/document/html/10de9253-de48-d006-3791-509d77e2a509.htm) to apply the transforms above and produce 3D coordinates from 2D pixel locations.

The key to doing this successfully this providing comprehensive `IInputArray objectPoints` and `IInputArray imagePoints` to `CvInvoke.CalibrateCamera`. Be sure to cause "excitation" by using many images, from many different perspectives.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and detailed explanation. It sounds like CvInvolk.ProjectPoints does exactly what I need as long as I calibrate. Perfect!

Comment: It does indeed :) Good calibration can be a pain but once it's done, it's done. Let me know if you have any trouble and kindly don't forget to upvote :P